# Laravel : Combine two tables using Model relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables :: `shops` and  `attachments` .  Shops has all the details for shop and attachments with all the  pictures for shop with `ref_id` as FK .

now for mobile app i have to list shops with  Shop title and one image.  I can achieve it using leftjoin as below.

```
Shop::select('shops.name as shop_name','attachments.name as picture')
            ->leftjoin('attachments','attachments.ref_id','=','shops.shop_id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

This returns just shop name and pictures ,
I want to achieve same results using relationships that i am not sure of how can i do that.  Can someone please advise me on that

**Edit**

**Shop Model**

```
public function attachments(){
     return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class, 'ref_id', 'shop_id');
}

 dd(Shop::find(34)->attachments()->first());
 dd(Shop::with('attachments')->get());
```

using first **dd** returns me attachment associated with 34 and but **with** query is not working  and returns just shop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, add the attachments relationship function to the `Shop` model.

```
class Shop 
{
    ...

    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class, 'ref_id', 'shop_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can access shop attachments by using the `->attachments()` on the `Shop` objects.

Example for getting all with pagination: ([eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading))

```
$shops = Shop::with('attachments')->paginate(10);

# access to first attachment of first shop
$shops->first()->attachments->first()->name
```

**Note**: It's better to use eager loading when you want to access all shops attachments to prevent the [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97197/6157616) query problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i did the same but its not returning me attachments data while ref_id is same as shop_id, is there anything that i am missing ?

Comment: Could you please share your complete query

Comment: its working thanks a lot , my mistake i was not looking relations index

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to define a One to Many relation in your Shop model (because one shop can have multiple attachements).

Maybe something like this :

```php
// In Shop model

public function attachments()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class, 'ref_id', 'shop_id');
}
```

Then you can use it like this (you don't have to use the find, you can use a where if you want) :

```php
$attachment = Shop::find(1)->attachments()->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this simple hasMany relation i know but  how do i do it with all records  like shop::all() with attachments , also cant it be one object using relationship like result is returned by joins #original: array:7 [
    "attachment_id" => 44
    "name" => "6724370727.jpg" , "shop_name"  :"name of shop "]  where shop name from shops and other from attachments

Comment: I don't know, may be take a look at `with()` or `whereHas()` methods: https://dev.to/othmane_nemli/laravel-wherehas-and-with-550o